# How do you clone a part to the Player in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have been making a game in Roblox, But I had one problem.

I wanted to make a debug GUI that one can use to spawn items at the Player Location, but I do not really know how to copy it to the player location.

If anyone is willing to help me fix this problem, I would appreciate that - a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Archivable property of the player's character (which's false by default) and set it to true, then call Character:Clone() to clone the character, set the property back to false, do what you need to do with the clone and done, you have a clone.